# Creating long orders using pinescript 5.0 not working

Tags: pine-script

I created a **Pinescript** strategy on **Tradingview**. I am trying to use 3 commands to **create an order** that will also setup a **STOP LOSS** and **TAKE PROFIT**. The commands being used are **strategy.enter** and **strategy.exit**

---

### The code

```
// ENTER THE LONG
1. strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long,    limit  =xlong_enter_level, when= ( strategy.position_size == 0  and enter_long == true ))

2. strategy.exit("Exit Long Profit","Long", profit =xlong_take_level / syminfo.mintick,  when=strategy.position_size > 0, comment="stop enacted" )

3.strategy.exit("Exit Long Stop", "Long",  stop   =xlong_stop_level / syminfo.mintick,  when=strategy.position_size > 0, comment="profit enacted")
```

---

### The Problem

Values I used:

```
x_long_entry = 41298
x_long_profit  = 45297
x_long_stop_loss = 40991
for the day of : 27 Sep 2021 at 17:00
```

From what I can see, the only thing working is the ENTRY (#1) -
The PROFIT and STOP are not working at all:
see: https://www.tradingview.com/x/GL3MyPTv/

Not sure if it the conversion : **xlong_take_level / syminfo.mintick**
is working properly.

If I were to **convert 60000 dollars to ticks**, what would I do?

---

### Things I have tried

- I have gone over this:
  https://backtest-rookies.com/2018/04/13/tradingview-stop-losses/
- and this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CxeTpU_t4Ks

but these are not working exactly (I am wondering if it is due to perhaps the version I am using (5.0) and the information from the links above were created for earlier versions of Pinescript.

How can one get this to work? Any help, hints or advice would be greatly appreciated

TIA

---

### Update

Hi @Andrey

These are the changes I made:

```
// Buy

strategy.entry("buy"  , strategy.long, limit=xlong_enter_level, stop=xlong_stop_level, when=strategy.position_size == 0  and enter_long == true )  
strategy.exit ("exit2", from_entry="buy", limit = xlong_take_level, stop =xlong_stop_level)
```

---

### These were the values used

[image]

Look at the Prices Bar on the right-hand-side. The colors (and lines drawn) represent the following:

- RED: the stop level (variable: x_long_stop_loss )
- GREEN : the take profit level ( variable: x_long_profit  )
- BLUE : the entry level ( variable: x_long_entry )

The **variables** are in the **blue box**  (it has debugging information in it)

---

### This was the result

[image]

The ENTRY has executed properly  **but** the **EXIT happens immediately** thereafter

I have also tried (for an exit)

```
strategy.exit ("exit2", from_entry="buy", limit = xlong_take_level, stop =xlong_stop_level, when = strategy.position_size > 0)
```

And get the same same result.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Some info about `strategy.exit`: 1) the `stop` & `limit` is absolute PRICE; 2) the `profit` & `loss` is relative POINTS from the position avg price; 3) use ONE `strategy.exit(..., limit = xlong_take_level, stop =xlong_stop_level, ...)`

Comment: @AndreyD - thanks for the response. See updates above TIA

Comment: I suppose the problem in `xlong_take_level` or `xlong_stop_level` value ... Without the source code it is too hard to guess where the problem is.